# ARP issue changing Internet connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, arp

Ok I'll jump right in the middle of things.
I usually connect my laptop to Internet through wifi at home and it works flawlessly. Problems come up when I try to connect to a friend of mine's wifi. The first time I noticed that when establishing connection Windows gave me "Limited access" and I was not able to surf the web. I found out that was an ARP issue. Typed `arp -d` in the *cmd* and everything started working as it should have. Moreover when I came back home and connected to my wifi there were no problem. Everytime I go to his house I have to `arp -d` my laptop.
My friend's router is a Sitecom 300N X3 (WL-348) and has DHCP enabled. Why is it working in this way?

Comment: It's most likely an issue with your friend's router.  Maybe it takes too long for the ARP response and it times out.  See if there is a way with your hardware to change the time out for an ARP repsonse.

Comment: I got a sneak peek of the Advanced tab of my NIC and I found an 'interesting' item called **Offload ARP**. In a nutshell it's a feature that, if disabled, can wake up the laptop when receives ARP requests. I bet it won't work but I'll give it a try. However I'll keep on searching for other solutions